# ASP MVC 5 link to same action without Parameter holding onto ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have an MVC5 app with a nav bar on top that has a link to the Entries Index page. This lists all entries in the system. The nav bar code is in a shared view _Layout.cshtml.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Entries", "Index", "Entry")
```

This normally builds the proper link of "/Entries/Index".

However those entries can be filtered by CompanyID with the {id} param. So /Entries/Index/1 would give me Entries for that Company. When you are on this screen the nav link is no longer simply /Entries/Index, but /Entries/Index/1.  The View seems to know that it is on that controller and adds the param.

I have tried the following to no avail.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Entries", "Index", "Entry", new {id=null }, null)
```

This even the syntax checker says is invalid. Unable to assign a null to an anonymous property for the id=null.

Not sure where to go next. I just want to force that link to be without a parameter no mater from where it is called. I don't want to have to hard code it.

Comment: In your first example, what does "Entry" represent?

Comment: ActionLink( <label>, <action>, <controller>)

Comment: so what you're saying is that when you're on the page: Index/Entry/1, the the menu link that was previously Index/Entry now has the id parameter added?

Comment: Exactly ("/Entry/Index/1"), but when I am on any other page it shows the link properly as ("/Entry/Index").

Comment: Have you tried: @Html.ActionLink("Entries", "Index", "Entry", new {id="" }, null)

Comment: That got it @markpsmith.  Write it up as an Answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Entries", "Index", "Entry", new {id="" }, null)
```

This will clear out the 'ambient ' route values from your nav links.  Here's a [blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/removing-route-values-from-linksurls-in.html) which explains it.